# DRYing up an Angular2 TypeScript Class

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm relatively new to TypeScript. I have a need to implement two route guards that share a common function and state.

When I attempt to extend a injectable class with a constructor, the resulting class does not receive instances of the private members.

Contrived example:

```
// guard-base.ts

@Injectable()
export abstract class GuardBase {
  constructor(
    private sharedState: SharedState,
  ) {}

  sharedMethod(): boolean {. . .}
}


// authentication-required.guard.ts

@Injectable()
export class RouteGuard extends GuardBase implements CanActivate {
  canActivate(): Promise<boolean> {
    console.log(this);
    // this.sharedState equals undefined at this point
  }
}
```

Do I have to provide the constructor arguments in the `RouteGuard` class? What I would like to do is encapsulate all of the imports and the shared method on the base class. Is that possible? If not, what's the best way to accomplish what I would like to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even other languages expect you to provide a new constructor for the new class (complete with parameters), then pass those parameters into the parent class's constructor to do what you're asking about. http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/5089e0/how-to-use-super-keyword-in-typescript/

Use `super(sharedState)` to pass the `sharedState` parameter from the child into the parent's constructor.

If you want to access a member variable from the parent class, use `protected` instead of `private`.

Comment: Gotcha. Hmm. I was hoping for something a bit more elegant. Will I have the same issue when extending a non-abstract class?

Comment: @Brandon- yes, this is the same for all classes, abstract or concrete.

Comment: Thank you for the help. It's not quite as DRY as the Python I used to write, but it will work :)